# DataTable Iteration And Fill Up

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to iterate through a 5 row 8 column DataTable (excluding the table headers etc). I need to go on filling each cell with string data and after the 8th cell has been reached, I will go to next row. Diagrammatically exactly like this:

[image: Routine]

How can this be achieved? 
**The problem that I am facing is that I am unable to write the nested loops which will iterate through the cells *row wise* and fill a string data** similar to this:

```
Artificial Intelligence 
Faculty: John Doe
Room: LS110
```

**This string above is the content of one cell of the data table. Other cells would be filled with similar strings.** The output would be similar:

[image]

This I need to do to convert to a HTML table later on.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the input? What is the challenge?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The input is a string data. The challenge is I am simply failing to write the loop to do this up. This is a part of a routine making software which uses GA to formulate routine.

Comment: It woul be helpful to see that string ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Similar to this: Artificial Intelligence
Faculty: John Doe
Room: LS110

Comment: Also, what is this string meant to be? Is it one field of one row? If so, how do you want tp  fill the other fields? The question is rather unclear.

Comment: @TimSchmelter adding more data to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got stuck, but if you don't know how to create the table and fill it with data:

```
string input = "Artificial Intelligence Faculty: John Doe Room: LS110";
var dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    dt.Columns.Add("Per-" + i);            

DataRow tue = dt.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    tue.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow wed = dt.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    wed.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow thu = dt.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    thu.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow fri = dt.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    fri.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow sat = dt.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    sat.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
```

**Update**: If you want the first column to contain the week-day:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(" "); // for the day
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    dt.Columns.Add("Per-" + i);

DataRow tue = dt.Rows.Add();
tue.SetField(0, "Tue");
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    tue.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow wed = dt.Rows.Add();
wed.SetField(0, "Wed");
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    wed.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow thu = dt.Rows.Add();
thu.SetField(0, "Thu");
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    thu.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow fri = dt.Rows.Add();
fri.SetField(0, "Fri");
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    fri.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
DataRow sat = dt.Rows.Add();
sat.SetField(0, "Sat");
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    sat.SetField("Per-" + i, input);
```

Comment: This is it! I was frustrated with my low experience with DataTable. Thanks!.

Comment: @Debojyoti: i have edited the answer to show how to add the day-column if that was desired.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Now I have a starting point. You were most helpful.